# How to add a class in wordpress selected menu?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a class to highlight the selected menu in wordpress. I have done this in html by the following code.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
    <li class="active-link"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>

    <li><a href="">Our Services</a></li>

    <li><a href="">Case Studies</a></li>
    <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can i do this in wordpress?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

used this code

Add this line off code **function.php**

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
     if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
             $classes[] = 'active ';  // your new class
     }
     return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [nav_menu_css_class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class) in wordpress.